# making multiple operations atomic in sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am creating a mobile application in flutter where I need to do entries in the transaction table and also need to update the balance in the user table. Whenever a new transaction is to be added I first check the current balance of the user, add the entry in the transaction table and update the balance. My question is how can I make the entire operation atomic. Say if the update balance fails because for any reason how can I roll back from the transaction table also.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what [SQLite transactions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) are for! (Sorry for the unfortunate name of your table which is also called transaction)

More info on how to use transactions in sqflite here:

https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/sql.md#transaction

some copy/pasted information for convenience:

#### transaction

`transaction` handle the 'all or nothing' scenario. If one command fails (and throws an error), all other commands are reverted.

```dart
await db.transaction((txn) async {
  await txn.insert('my_table', {'name': 'my_name'});
  await txn.delete('my_table', where: 'name = ?', whereArgs: ['cat']);
});
```

- Make sure to sure the inner transaction object - `txn` in the code above - is used in a transaction (using the `db` object itself will cause a deadlock),
- You can throw an error during a transaction to cancel a transaction,
- When an error is thrown during a transaction, the action is cancelled right away and previous commands in the transaction are reverted,
- No other concurrent modification on the database (even from an outside process) can happen during a transaction,
- The inner part of the transaction is called only once, it is up to the developer to handle a try-again loop - assuming it can succeed at some point.